# Swift - Iterate through all cases of a nested enumeration

Tags: swift, enums

I have the following nested enumeration setup:

```
enum UserSettings:Equatable {
    case emailSettings(EmailSettings), notificationSettings(NotificationSettings), socialSettings(SocialSettings), gameSettings(GameSettings)

    enum EmailSettings:CaseIterable {
        case enableEmails, allowPromotionalEmails
    }

    enum NotificationSettings:CaseIterable {
        case enableAppNotifications, getNewFollowerNotifications, getTaggedInPostNotifications
    }

    enum SocialSettings:CaseIterable {
        case allowChallengeInvites, allowCrewRequests, allowLeagueInvites, allowPostTagging, allowUsersToFollow, appearOffline, crewOnlyMessaging, matchesArePublic, profileIsPublic
    }

    enum GameSettings:CaseIterable {
        case syncNewMatchesOnStartup
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to pass a "UserSettings" value to a cell in `cellForRowAt` via the following code:

```
let cell = settingsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yesNoSettingsCell", for: indexPath) as! YesNoSettingsCell
let currentSetting = UserSettings.SocialSettings.allCases[indexPath.row]
cell.passedUserSetting = currentSetting
return cell
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
"Cannot assign value of type 'UserSettings.SocialSettings' to type 'UserSettings'"
```

Changing the code in `cellForRowAt` to:

```
let currentSetting = UserSettings.socialSettings().allCases[indexPath.row]
```

produces the following error:

```
"Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"
```

What am I missing? How do I enumerate through all cases of a nested enumeration?

Comment: `let currentSetting = UserSettings.SocialSettings.allCases[indexPath.row]; cell.passedUserSetting = .socialSettings(currentSetting)` ?

Comment: `cell.passedUserSetting = UserSettings.socialSettings(currentSetting)` then? Note that previous shouldn't have the space `.socialSettings (currentSetting)` => `.socialSettings(currentSetting)`, but I guess you fixed that typo

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Make sure you add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error
`"Cannot assign value of type 'UserSettings.SocialSettings' to type 'UserSettings'"` is on `cell.passedUserSetting = currentSetting`.
You are giving context, but `passedUserSetting` is a `UserSettings`.

But when you do:

```
let currentSetting = UserSettings.SocialSettings.allCases[indexPath.row]
```

So, it means `currentSetting` is a `UserSettings.SocialSettings`.

So you are trying to set a value of type B to expected value of type A. It won't work.

You can have with you enum a `UserSettings` with a `UserSettings.SocialSettings`:

```
cell.passedUserSetting = .socialSettings(currentSetting)
```